# replace line break with 2 spans in php

Tags: php, html, regex

Consider the following HTML string:

```
<p>This is line 1 <br /> and this is line 2</p>
```

How can i replace the above with the following string using PHP / Regex

```
<p><span class="single-line">This is line 1</span><span class="single-line">and this is line 2</span></p>
```

Comment: The CSS spec teaches you to not create meta-representation with class attributes and div/spans. So please don't do it. The answer is: DOMDocument + Xpath.

Comment: what about divs? why do you not use div instead of span? div is a block element which should work for you like a charm.

Comment: div is not a valid element inside a p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works but I would advise you not to rely on regular expressions for HTML parsing / transformation:

```
$string = '<p>This is line 1 <br /> and this is line 2</p>';
$pattern = '~([^<>]+)<br[[:blank:]]*/?>([^<>]+)~i';
$replacement = '<span class="single-line">$1</span><span class="single-line">$2</span>';

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not really suggest that you actually do it (because IMHO you're misusing markup and classes), however it's actually pretty simple:

you replace

```
<p>
```

with

```
<p><span class="single-line">
```

and

```
<br />
```

with

```
</span><span class="single-line">
```

and finally

```
</p>
```

with

```
</span></p>
```

A PHP function that can replace strings is [`strtr`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/strtr).

Note that this works only for exactly the HTML fragment you've given in your question. If you need this more precise, you should consider using `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` as I already commented above.

Comment: I'll try this changing the spans into div's considering semantics. I'm not sure about the formatting because our client uses tinymce to insert the text into the database.